# geom_density to match geom_histogram binwitdh

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a line to a distribution bar plot in ggplot2 to show the average distribution but am having trouble.

A ggplot call like this:

```
ggplot(x, aes(date_received)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), binwidth=30) +
    geom_density()
```

gives me the histogram bars for every 30 days worth of observations, but the density line is tracking the count for every individual day, as seen below (the static at the bottom is from `geom_density`.

[image]

Is it possible to add a `geom_density` layer to overlay a line that will show the average for the count of 30 day groups of observations like the `binwidth` in `geom_histogram`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to answer of Brian S. Diggs given in this [e-mail](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280588.html) you should multiply value of `..count..` in `geom_density(`) by the value of `binwidth=` in `geom_histogram()`.

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,100,15))

ggplot(df,aes(x))+
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 2.5)+
      geom_density(aes(y=2.5 * ..count..))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the histogram uses normalized counts

Comment: @jdmartin86 If you use `ncount` in `geom_histogram()` then density code should be `geom_density(aes(y = ..ndensity..))`

Comment: Very helpful! I added a variable bw (bin width). So, I wrote `geom_density(aes(y=bw * ..count..))`. If geom_histogram is not plotted, it is important to know the bw, so the counts totally depends on it.