# Programatically scale density curve made with geom_density to similar height to geom_histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we make a histogram

```
set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(1000)
qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +
geom_histogram()
```

to which we add a density line

```
qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +
geom_histogram() +
geom_density()
```

the density line is *so low it is hardy visible*, so it can be [scaled to match the height of the histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404002/geom-density-to-match-geom-histogram-binwitdh):

```
qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  geom_density(aes(y=0.22 * ..count..))
```

#### Question

How can we adjust the density line programaticlaly when not using the `binwidth` argument to `geom_histogram` (i.e. when using the `bins` argument).

The desired output is a `geom_histogram(bins = ...)` with sensibly scaled density line that *doesn't* rely on any manual computation of a multiplier / hard coding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with the caveat that you have to specify the numbers of bins beforehand. This is merely because layers can share data but not don't share calculated parameters. I.e. the density layer does not know about the `bins`/`binwidth` parameter in the histogram layer. The following requires ggplot2 v3.3.0.

```
nbins <- 30
qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +
  geom_histogram(bins = nbins) +
  geom_density(aes(y = stage(nbins, after_stat = count * diff(range(x))/nbins)))
```

Comment: In addition to your answer, an observation, I *think* `geom_density` will always have tails extending beyond the `range(x)`. So multiplying by a scalar (e.g. 1.1) could make the density line even more in line with the bars (presuming that is desirable) i.e.  `geom_density(aes(y = stage(nbins, after_stat = count * diff(1.1 * range(x))/nbins))) `.

Comment: You can test this by using `stage(nbins, after_stat = count * diff(rangex <<- range(x))/nbins)`. For me, `rangex == range(x)` is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use density estimate instead of count. It can be easily accessed now via `after_stat`. Take a look also at `ndensity` option — maybe that's you were lookin for?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(1000)

# Example of kernel density estimate usage
den <- qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +
  geom_histogram(aes(y= after_stat(density))) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle("Density estimate")

# Example of kernel density estimate usage, scale to a maximum of 1
nden <- qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +
  geom_histogram(aes(y= after_stat(ndensity))) +
  geom_density(aes(y= after_stat(ndensity))) +
  ggtitle("Density estimate, scaled to 1")

# Plot
den | nden
```

[image]