# General rule of overlaying density plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I`m a novice with the R programming language. What is the standard/general method for overlaying a density curve on a histogram using ggplot2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that to multiply value of `..count..` in in the density plot call by the value of whatever the binwidth is in the histogram call.

You can do it as follows:

```
set.seed(100)
a = data.frame(z = rnorm(10000))
binwidthVal=0.1
ggplot(a, aes(x=z)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidthVal) + 
geom_density(colour='red', aes(y=binwidthVal * ..count..))
```

[image]

[Credit to Brian Diggs for the idea.](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280588.html)

EDIT: Seems like there is already a perfectly good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404002/geom-density-to-match-geom-histogram-binwitdh)

Answer (score 2):

It depends wether you want an empirical density estimate or to fit a theoretical density. In both cases, you'd need to match the width of histogram bins to the density.

For the empirical kernel density estimates:

```
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000)
)

binwidth <- 0.1
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(count * binwidth)),
               color = "red")
```

[image]

Theoretical density estimates don't live in ggplot2 but in extention packages. Disclaimer: I'm the author of the following package, so I'm biased:

```
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth) +
  stat_theodensity(aes(y = after_stat(count * binwidth)),
                   color = "red")
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to bother with setting binwidths you can also scale the histogram to density instead:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density))) +
  geom_density(color = "red")
```

[image]

Note: `after_stat()` requires ggplot2 v3.3.0, earlier versions use `stat()`.

Comment: Thank you. The third alternative worked. the other two gave the following error message:Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomBar,  
  object 'binwidth' not found

Comment: That probably is because `binwidth` is a variable that you would assign yourself beforehand, such as in the first code chunk of my answer.