# ridgeline plot with frequencies (count) instead of density, on second y-axis and rectangle background

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

I would like to add frequencies on a second y-axis to a ridgeline plot using `ggplot2` and `ggridges`

I found a tutorial adding the frequencies as numbers with `geom_text` (https://rdrr.io/cran/ggridges/man/stat_binline.html), however, I would prefer to add them as a second y-axis.

Of course I very appreciate solutions outside `ggridges` to get a similar plot.

**Example data:**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(lubridate)

# datapoints
data_timepoint <- data.frame(type=factor(c("A","B","C","D")),
                             start=as.Date(c("1990-01-01","2000-01-01","2010-01-01","2012-01-01")),
                             stop=as.Date(c(rep("2022-01-01",4))))

                             
                             
# frequencies                             
data_freq <- data.frame(type=c("A","A","B","C","D","D","D"),
                        year=ymd(year(as.Date(c("1991-01-01","1991-01-01","2005-01-01","2016-01-01","2013-01-01","2013-01-01","2015-01-01"))),truncated=2L))
                                 




# plot
ggplot(data_timepoint) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=start, xmax=stop,
                ymin=type, ymax=as.numeric(type)+0.9), fill="lightblue") +
  geom_density_ridges(data=data_freq, aes(x=year,y=type),stat = "binline",
                      bins = 1, scale = 0.95, draw_baseline = FALSE, alpha=.5, binwidth=10,center=20) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year",date_labels = "%Y") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = -2)) +
  labs(title="",y="Type",x="Year")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Desired output:**
[image]

Comment: you have so few data points, I can hardly see the usefulness of a density plot... - or maybe you have way more data points and you want to share sample data that resembles  it more closely? (maybe use the example from `?geom_density_ridges`?

Comment: thank you. yeah the real data has way more data points. I thought the sample data should be small and I am using a long data format. Therefore I gave sample data that represents my data structure the best.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957549/overlaying-histograms-with-ggplot2-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404002/geom-density-to-match-geom-histogram-binwitdh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You technically don't really have a secondary y axis - you just want to show frequency instead of density. You can generally show frequency by using `..count..` or with newer syntax `after_stat(count)` as your y aesthetic. ggridges doesn't seem to have count as a computed stat - therefore maybe fake your ggridges look with facets.

The example is adapted from ?geom_density_ridges

```r
library(ggplot2)

## swap x and y
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) +
## use y = after_stat(count) to show your frequency
  geom_density(aes(y =after_stat(count))) +
## change the y axis position to the right
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0), position = "r") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
## add facet, and put label to the left
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol = 1, strip.position = "l")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you go a step further, and let the facets overlap (which is the principle of a ridge plot: overlapping facets of a density plot), you will see that by adding an axis guide to a classic ridge plot, there will be overlap of those guides between the ridges (your facets). This doesn't look good.

This is irrespective of your stat, and will also happen with stat = "binline"

```r
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count..)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0), position = "r") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~cut, ncol = 1, strip.position = "l")  +
## let the facets overlap (make background and strip transparent)
  theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(-.3, "in"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank())

cowplot::stamp_bad(p)
```

[image]

To add your desired rectangle annotation, your approach is perfectly fine. Is the data actually structured as in your example or have you just created the second frame beforehand based on the first one? (This would be excellent and well done doing so)

Few more comments in the code

```
   
ggplot() +
## use different y - slightly depending on your desired look 
geom_rect(data = data_timepoint, aes(xmin=start, xmax=stop, ymin=0, ymax=1), fill="lightblue") +
geom_histogram(data= data_freq, aes(year)) +
## added pretty labels
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), position = "r", breaks = scales::breaks_pretty(n = 2)) +
## keep x as date
scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0)) +
facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, strip.position = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. I try to get a histogram distribution, therefore I used `stat = "binline"` .  probably I can combine `stat_bin` with `geom_rect` to get a plot similar to the desired output (i.e., histogram distribution on a geom).

Comment: thank you. I see your point regarding the classic ridge plot. I try to represent the distribution using histograms not density plots. can your approach be combined with `geom_rect` as shown in the desired output above?

Comment: nob probs. unfortunately I did not accomplish it. yeah it simply highlights the time span (first to last occurrence).

Comment: @ava I have added a suggestion with your geom_rect. Your approach seemed perfectly fine to me. Not sure if this is what you envisioned.